# YOCTO - MTD drivers implementation

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I want to change the current implementation of MTD (flash drives) while using YOCTO project, to support new commands using its **ioctl** commands. Yet, I couldn't find the implementation of the MTD flash drivers, just the **header** files and the usage of the driver while the kernel loads and makes the partitions. Can someone please point me to the the implementation files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the MTD drivers is not directly related to the Yocto Project, but part of the Linux kernel. So if you want to modify the drivers, you have to work on those in the kernel itself. They are located in the source tree at `drivers/mtd`.

See also:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/mtd

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. 
I already looked for in these directories, but what I am actually looking for is the implementation of the read and write functions in the  structures as **mtd_info** and **nand_flash_device**, I am looking for the actual signal toggling functions.

Comment: Here you go: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/mtd_info and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/nand_flash_device - yet it looks like the latter is not really a thing in the kernel. For finding out where something comes from and how the data flow is, bootlins elixir is a great tool!

Comment: I already looked there, in Elixir Cross Referencer and coudn't find the answer. I also tried to use **strace** to understand the exact flow of the function, and I always find myself reaching to some instance like


`mtd->_write(...)` 

or so, and this **_write(...)** implementation is what I am looking for.